# jquery chosen plugin shows internal frame

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jquery-chosen

I am currently facing an issue with using jquery plugin chosen with bootstrap. I have a page with two tabs and the first tab has a chosen enabled dropdown with 3 fields below it. This dropdown works perfectly fine.

However, on the second tab, the jquery chosen plugin does not show up correctly. I have tried to attach a screenshot below to explain the unusual behaviour. Any ideas ?

[image: Working example]

Notice the scrollbar on the extreme right which makes it look so awkward and difficult to scroll. The entire page below the dropdown is empty, but the scrollbar only covers about 50px..

[image: Not working example]

Has anybody seen this earlier ? Any suggestions/solutions. 
Note: The jquery plugin and bootstrap css are already included before the chosen css and chosen js.

Thanks,
Qadeer

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same issue using chosen inside tabs.
The scroll appears because the `<div class="tab-content">` overflow is set to auto in bootstrap css. `overflow: auto;` uses scrolling to display the content (more on the overflow property at [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp))

Changing tab-content div as follows fixed the issue for me:

```
<div class="tab-content" style="overflow: visible;">
```